# How to tell when calculating an Intercept Point between two moving objects, when it will never intercept?

Tags: vectors, linear-algebra

I'm not a maths person and the formulas you see on here with all the symbols is completely beyond me - I'm sorry. However I had help about 18 months ago to turn a provided formula into lua script to make the calculation for two aircraft to intercept each other. I will admit, I don't know why that formula works, and I wouldn't know how to change it to make it do other things; I need to get this working for a flight sim project, but learning all the maths for this one problem would take too long and I have no-one who could teach me. (I don't learn well from books). Please be understanding and not too critical of my lack of maths skills.

The premise is one aircraft will maintain it's course (target) and the other (interceptor) will alter it's course to intercept with the target aircraft at some point in the future.

The formula/code I made for that is this:

```
    -- Point intercept(Point const &shooter, double bullet_speed, Point const &target, Vector const &target_velocity)
    -- {
    --     double a = bullet_speed*bullet_speed - target_velocity.dot(target_velocity);
    --     double b = -2*target_velocity.dot(target-shooter);
    --     double c = -(target-shooter).dot(target-shooter);

    --     return target+largest_root_of_quadratic_equation(a,b,c)*target_velocity;
    -- }

  local targetMINUSInterceptor   = TVF.VecSubtract(interceptorVec3Point, targetVec3Point)
  local targetVelocityDotProduct = TVF.VecDot(targetVelocityAsVec3, targetVelocityAsVec3)

  local a = interceptorSpeedAsNumber * interceptorSpeedAsNumber - targetVelocityDotProduct
  local b = -2 * TVF.VecDot(targetVelocityAsVec3, targetMINUSInterceptor)
  local c = -TVF.VecDot(targetMINUSInterceptor, targetMINUSInterceptor)

  local result = TVF.VecAdd(targetVec3Point, (TVF.MultiplyVectorByNumber(targetVelocityAsVec3, TVF.GetLargestRootOfQuadraticEquation(a,b,c))))
```

Now, that all works perfectly, but only IF both aircraft are travelling in directions and speeds that CAN intercept (even with required turns for the Interceptor).

However, if you have, for example, the target aircraft heading West, and East of that target you have the Interceptor aircraft heading East (i.e. moving away from each other and already are tail to tail to each other), and allowing for the fact that the interceptor can't go fast enough to catch up and overtake the target aircraft, then the above calculation/formula still gives a position vector, however it's either 'off the map' or in some weird direction and massive magnitude that makes no practical sense.

I need to know when this calculation (or a modified version of it) gives a possible interception point, and also when it can't give an interception point. This will allow me to make a branching decision in my code to warn the players when an interception is not possible and the target aircraft would have to change it's direction and/or speed and try again.

Could someone please help? My maths level is very basic trig, so I'd really appreciate it if you could spell it out for me or give me the corrected formula with explanations words for all the terms please.

Comment: I see that you're a well seasoned member of the Stackoverflow community... Have you tried asking this question there?

Comment: Well I had originally, but I didn't get very far because it wasn't a 'coding' issue so much as a maths issue. In the end the help and formula I got was pointed to me from a redditor on a maths 'simulation' page about leading a target when shooting a bullet. Because the theory was the same as a bullet intercepting a target to an aircraft intercepting another, I made it work, but it obviously doesn't take into account someone shooting in a direction that could never hit the target! lol, and that's the bit I need to work out.

Comment: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/ seems to be the right place for this question ;).

Comment: It is a coding issue. The example shows how use of object-oriented programming obscures the calculations, and also how using long names make things unreadable.  I can't imagine that people in the softwareengineering and  langdev groups at stackexchange wouldn't have strong opinions and lots to say about that!

Comment: @JosBergervoet, Re, "long names make things unreadable." After spending 45 years as a software developer, I will say that short names are, um, OK, i guess, as long as you don't need any code comments to explain what they mean. As a code reviewer—a role I have played many times—the moment I see a comment that explains a variable, I'm gonna demand, "Get rid of the comment, and change the name so that the variable explains itself." There's a couple of reasons for that, and I'm forced to keep this paragraph small, so just trust me. They're good reasons.

Comment: @solomon There are reasons in favor of good descriptive names (which need a certain length), but they're not always overruling the other objective of keeping the equations readable, especially with lots of complicated formulas. In situations like that, even being able to use `x` instead of `x1` is a big improvement. The fact that you need comments between the formulas is in that case evident, but that's how math books have been written for 5 centuries now! The text in there is just to explain the equations...

Comment: As it is currently written, this appears to be a coding or programming problem, rather than a mathematics problem.  It is very likely that it can be reformulated into a mathematics problem, but that is not how it is being presented right now.